# addEventListener for only one time on any one element in forEach loop javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an array of NodeList. I loop through every NodeList element and add click event Listener.

```
var itemsList = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
itemList.forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener('click', () => {
       console.log('clicked');
   })
})
```

As soon as I clicked any one of the items I want to remove the event listener for all the other items as well.
It doesn't matter each item is clicked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it directly without jQuery or anything, and without overcomplicating it, you could do something like this:

```js
const itemsList = document.querySelectorAll('.items');

const onClick = () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  itemsList.forEach(item => {
    item.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
  });
};

itemsList.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', onClick);
});
```

Basically you keep a reference to the click function, and the function itself removes itself from all nodes in the list.

If you want to know which item was clicked, you can add a parameter to the `onClick` function, which will be the click event, from which you can get the item that was clicked, like so:

```js
const itemsList = document.querySelectorAll('.items');

const onClick = event => {
  const clickedItem = event.target
  console.log('clicked on ' + clickedItem.textContent);

  itemsList.forEach(item => {
    item.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
  });
};

itemsList.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', onClick);
});
```

Something along these lines will let you get a reference to which item was actually clicked.

Comment: It works but how can I get the text content of that item

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more expressive

```js
var itemsList = document.querySelectorAll('.items');

const updateClickListener = (list, callback, operation = 'add') => {
  itemList.forEach(item => {
    item[`${operation}EventListener`]('click', () => {
        callback();
        updateClickListener(list, () => {}, 'remove');
    })
  })
}

updateClickListener(
 list, 
 () => {
   console..log('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very concise using jquery

```
var handler=function(){
   //your logic of click event
   alert('clicked')
}

// handle click and add class
$('.items').on("click", function(){
  handler();
  $('.items').not(this).off("click");
})
```

This will removes every other click events after clicking the first one. If you want to remove every event including the first clicked, then remove the `not()` method from my code

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add the listener to an ancestor of your elements i.e. `document` + a target check on which element was clicked, if you need to remove this listener you only have to remove it once

```js
function handleClick(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("items")) {
    alert(event.target.textContent)
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
    <div id="app">
      <li class="items">1</li>
      <li class="items">2</li>
      <li class="items">3</li>
      <li class="items">4</li>
      <li class="items">5</li>
    </div>
```